# Комбинатор on и каррированая функция fst

Tags: функции, haskell, функциональное-программирование

Наткнулся на следующие выражение, с использованием комбинатора on:

```
 foo :: Num c => c -> c -> c
 foo = curry fst `on` (^2)
```

Вопрос: Как работает данная конструкция?

В частности мне непонятно следующие:

1. Почему мы используем fst в качестве каррированной функции, если на вход мы подаем два аргумента которые идут после комбинатора `on`
2. Как данные аргументы возводятся в квадрат, если они становятся каррированными только перед комбинатором `on`
3. Что происходит в данной конструкции на самом деле, исходя из конкретного примера использования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Почему мы используем fst в качестве каррированной функции, если на вход мы подаем два аргумента которые идут после комбинатора on

`fst` не каррированная функция, мы как раз делаем ее каррированной с помощью комбинатора `curry`
т.е. была функция `fst`

```hs
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

а получаем новую функцию `curry fst`

```hs
curry fst :: a -> b -> a
```

> 2. Как данные аргументы возводятся в квадрат, если они становятся каррированными только перед комбинатором on

Из сигнатуры полученной функции видно, что теперь это функция от двух аргументов, которая возвращает результат совпадающий по типу с первым аргументом, т.е. она вполне может принять возведенные в квадрат числа и вернуть число.

> 3. Что происходит в данной конструкции на самом деле, исходя из конкретного примера использования.

Выполним подстановку согласно определению `on`

```hs
foo = curry fst `on` (^2)
=>
foo = \x y -> (curry fst) ((^2) x) ((^2) y)
=>
foo x y = curry fst (x^2) (y^2)
```

Теперь подстановку `curry fst`

```hs
curry fst
=>
\a b -> fst (a, b)
=>
\a b -> a
```

Теперь подставляем полученную функцию в предыдущее определение

```
foo x y = (\a b -> a) (x^2) (y^2)
=>
foo x y = x^2
```

Итого, `foo` принимает два аргумента, второй игнорирует, а первый возводит в квадрат.

---

Даже если проигнорировать тот факт, что `on` здесь совершенно не нужна, `curry fst` не нужна тем более, ее можно было бы заменить на эквивалентную ей `const`.

```hs
foo = const `on` (^2)
```